# How To Remove Content Types?

Tags: nodes

I installed a custom module that created few content type that I'm no longer need it. I disable and uninstall that module but I still have the content type. And it bother me every time I see it. So I try to delete it however, I cant because for some reason doesnt have the delete button. So now I have 5 content type that I don't need. Can anyone have a solution on how to remove these content types ?

In this picture you will see that doesnt allow me to delete the content type.
[image]

Comment: Are you certain that you completely uninstalled the module(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing else helps, delete them in the database directly (its probably advisable to make a backup):

```
DELETE FROM `your_database`.`node_type` WHERE `node_type`.`type` = \'blog_post\'"
```